# Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set for Simple VBA For loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have, what I thought, was a fairly simple bit of code to locate specific data in one sheet (4) by its depth and match it to the same depth columns in another sheet (3). Unfortunately it keeps popping a

> Run-time error '91' : Object Variable or With block variable not set.

I have the paste range for the data (Using an Address/Match statement) located in columns S and T of sheet 4.  The code is following:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim Row1 As Long, Row2 As Long

For i = 3 To 4665
    If wb.Sheets(4).Range("S" & i).Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA) And wb.Sheets(4).Range("T" & i).Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        Row1 = wb.Sheets(4).Range("S" & i).Row
        Row2 = wb.Sheets(4).Range("T" & i).Row
        wb.Sheets(3).Range("X" & Row1 & ":X" & Row2).Value = wb.Sheets(4).Range("E" & i).Value
        wb.Sheets(3).Range("Y" & Row1 & ":Y" & Row2).Value = wb.Sheets(4).Range("F" & i).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake I am missing but I can't find the bug (or bugs). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes, you didnt set `wb` equal to anything. you defined it as a workbook, but you never told it which workbook it was.

Comment: Also `Row1 = wb.Sheets(4).Range("S" & i).Row` and `Row2 = wb.Sheets(4).Range("T" & i).Row` are going to return the same value, `i`

Comment: you can combine the four lines in the IF with: `wb.Sheets(3).Range("X" & i & ":Y" & i).Value =  wb.Sheets(4).Range("E" & i & ":F" & i).Value`

Comment: You never assign anything to `wb`, but still try to access it's property `Sheets`. That won't work. You have to assign a workbook to `wb` before you can use it.

Comment: Thank you all for catching that mistake. Can't believe I missed that.@ScottCraner thanks for the heads up on the .Row functions. Switched them over to .Value and the match function provided the actual row numbers I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set wb = activeworkbook
```

There are two types of variables in VBA (forgive me, this isn't the right terminology but it is close). One points to a piece of data (like a string or number). The other points to an "object", which is a container for all sorts of things. An object has values, an object has methods you can call.

Workbook is an object. You can access data from a workbook ("get me sheet1, workbook!") and you can call methods on a workbook (`workbook.add`).

With a simple data variable, you can say `filename = C:\exam.txt`

But an object must be `SET`. Anytime you see "Object not set" that means you did something like `wb = activeworkbook` instead of `SET wb = activeworkbook`.

The other scenario is you forgot to set the variable to an object, like you did above.